# How to understand the "type" field in the result of using "explain" on Mysql?

Tags: java, mysql

When I used "explain" on Mysql to view some information about the execution of the statement, the value of the field type made me very confused!
**Table creation statement**

```sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `actor`;
CREATE TABLE `actor` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `update_time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
INSERT INTO `actor` (`id`, `name`, `update_time`) VALUES (1,'a','2017-12-2 15:27:18'), (2,'b','2017-12-22 15:27:18'), (3,'c','2017-12-22 15:27:18');

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `film`;
CREATE TABLE `film` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `idx_name` (`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
INSERT INTO `film` (`id`, `name`) VALUES (3,'film0'),(1,'film1'),(2,'film2');

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `film_actor`;
CREATE TABLE `film_actor` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `film_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `actor_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `remark` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `idx_film_actor_id` (`film_id`,`actor_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
INSERT INTO `film_actor` (`id`, `film_id`, `actor_id`) VALUES (1,1,1),(2,1,2),(3,2,1);
```

When I execute

```sql
explain select * from film 
left join film_actor on film.id = film_actor.film_id
left join actor on actor.id = film_actor.actor_id
where film.id = 1;
```

The type of each table is as follows
[image]
| table      | type  |
| ---------- | ----- |
| film       | const |
| film_actor | ref   |
| actor      | ALL   |

When I execute

```sql
explain select * from film 
left join film_actor on film.id = film_actor.film_id
left join actor on actor.id = film_actor.actor_id
```

The type of each table is as follows
[image]

`eq_ref` is interpreted as `One row is read from this table for each combination of rows from the previous tables.`

`ref` is interpreted as  `All rows with matching index values are read from this table for each combination of rows from the previous tables.`

But the difference between these two queries is only a where condition, and no related fields are modified. Why are the types of `film_actor` and `actor` tables completely different in the two queries? How to understand this phenomenon?

Thanks in advance.